# Modal Bootstrap with jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button, triggers, modal-dialog

i'm have a form and i need to trigger a bootstrap modal when i'm click a the submit buttton
this is what i have but doenst work:

```js
$("#formulario").submit(function () {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#formularioModal").click();
  $("#progresBarUpload").addClass("active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
  <div class="pull-left">
    <!--  data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"    -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="boton" >
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved"></i>
          Guardar cuarderno
    </button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-link">Cancelar</button>
  </div><!-- /pull-right -->
</div><!-- /col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10 -->

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="formularioModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <!-- <div class="modal-dialog">-->

   <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
       <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center">
           <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                   <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                       Guardando archivos...
                   </h4>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body">
                   <div class="progress">
                       <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%;" id="progresBarUpload">       
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>            
   </div>
</div>
```

"I need the modal "Loading" appears with the "submit" but since jQuery, not the click event that comes by default bootstrap"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Bootstrap JavaScript page](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage) where you can find how to manipulate with modals. There are many options which makes you able to show / dimiss modals and even more. I have edited your code and it should be working for you.

**Using JavaScript**:

```
$("#formulario").submit(function () {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#formularioModal').modal('show')
});
```

**Using data-target on button**:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch modal</button>
```

You can see both of those examples live on [bootply.com](http://www.bootply.com/x3TQ1nSAMF)

Also you can find out how to create actions on event like modal dimmis so you will be able to set cookies to don't show modal for subscription for example. Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your submit button:

```
 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formularioModal"
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/c5650t81/)